# Kendo Grid: getting an instance in a Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

this follows directly on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447578/kendo-grid-getting-widget-instance-in-angular) (with an additional question hence I thought should be a new post?)

The link above shows how to get a grid instance in Angular (thanks to Lars)

So, following on from this last example, I now have added the following directive..

```
<body>    
<div data-ng-app="app">     
<div data-ng-controller="Grid as vm">
        <div id='aa'>
    <div pckendo id='bb' kendo-grid='grid' 
       k-options="vm.options"></div>  
    </div>

 </div>
</div>      
</body>
```

and in the .js added

```
angular
.module("app", ["kendo.directives"])
.controller("Grid", Grid)
.directive('pckendo', PCKendo);
....
function PCKendo() {

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var instance = element;
    var vm = scope.vm;

    vm.msg = "";
    var grid = scope.grid;

}

return {
    link: link
}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/zL46oz49/3/) for full example.

Rather than getting the instance in the controller, I would like to get it via a directive (as from what I understand this is a better place to do event handling etc)

I have tried a few things in there, but haven't been able to get the grid instance, so any further help here would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you do the same thing; you need to wait for the `kendoRendered` event, e.g. like this (note that this example may not conform to angular best practices (re isolate scope etc.)):

```
function PCKendo($timeout) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on("kendoRendered", function (e) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.vm.setMessage("one col");
                scope.grid.hideColumn(1);
            });

            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.vm.setMessage("all cols");
                    scope.grid.showColumn(1);
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
    }

    return {
        link: link
    }
}
```

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/ECipu))

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I didn't realise still had to "wait" (ie on the kendoRendered) in here, but it works perfectly. Thanks heaps again! I am now starting to feel I will be able to get what I need done with this grid. Cheers